# ActiveMQ topic subscriber groups

Tags: activemq-classic

I'm new to ActiveMQ and I've done lots of googling and searches within stackoverflow as well and still not seeing a clear answer to the following question:

Can ActiveMQ be told/configured to send a published message to only ONE subscriber, from a group of subscribers, in a round-robin fashion?

Let me explain the scenario better...  In our production systems we obviously run more than one server for each web app module.  So let's say we have webapp module "USER" running on 10 servers.  Each server, at startup will subscribe to topic "TOPIC1".  Some other module (or external system) publishes a message to TOPIC1.  I don't want all 10 servers to receive the exact same message.  Rather I want ActiveMQ to realize that those 10 servers are subscribed to TOPIC1 as a "group" and to pick only one of them in round-robin fashion to send the message to.  Can ActiveMQ be configured to do this?

Before you answer "Use message groups!" let me tell you I've read all about them and it appears to be a "sticky" load-balancing mechanism with ActiveMQ.  Meaning, of those 10 servers, it will pick one (at random I guess) and from that point on any message published to TOPIC1 will always go to that server and there's no way for me to specify that servers 1-10 are participating in a "subscription group" for TOPIC1 and that they're to be given TOPIC1 messages in a round-robin fashion.

Can someone confirm or deny my assumptions?  If confirm, any topic subscribe examples that would achieve the above scenario?

Thanks,
-Jac

Comment: This sounds more like a call for using Queues rather than topics.

Comment: As Tim pointed out, use Queues and configure the Queue to distribute in a round-robin fashion. See http://activemq.apache.org/dispatch-policies.html